# Shared datasource in jboss applications on wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, cron, wildfly, jndi

I am fearly new to this. 
I am having a hard time on how to resolve the issue of having a war file deployed with an jndi datasource given in a -ds.xml file and a jar file which have to be executed as a linux cron job and use the same datasource.

The war file is a spring boot 2 application with endpoint services communicating with a database while the jar file includes a data migration job migrating data from a file to database.

As some of the data in the database are encrypted, i need to use the same datasource accross the two applications to encrypt and decrypt data in the same way.

I have an -ds.xml file with the datasource which is deployed on wildfly.

```
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/XXX-DS" pool-name="MariaDBDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:8080/xxxx</connection-url>
    <driver>mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar</driver>
    <driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <security>
        <user-name>xxxx</user-name>
        <password>xxxx</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Any help on how to do this?